# Flutter change main appbar title on other pages

Tags: dart, flutter

Looking for some assistance with changing the AppBar `title` on subsequent pages, so me being tabs and some not.  `MyApp` is defined on the authentication page of my app.  I then goto a new page that holds the tabs, then I have other pages off some of the tab pages, what I want to be able to do is, instead of putting another `AppBar` under the main one, I just want to change the `title` of the main `AppBar` when I am on any of the other pages.

Any ideas how to do this, I saw 1 example that did not fit because my tabs are setup different and could not make it fit, thought maybe there was a way to define the title initially so that I can change state or something and change the title.

Any ideas or thoughts on this?

Answer (score 8):

You can add a `TabController` and add `listen` to it such that you call `setState` whenever you are switching between the `Tab`s, and change the `AppBar` title accordingly.

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home:new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  final List<MyTabs> _tabs = [new MyTabs(title: "Teal",color: Colors.teal[200]),
  new MyTabs(title: "Orange",color: Colors.orange[200])
  ];
  MyTabs _myHandler ;
  TabController _controller ;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _myHandler = _tabs[0];
    _controller.addListener(_handleSelected);
  }
  void _handleSelected() {
    setState(() {
       _myHandler= _tabs[_controller.index];
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(_myHandler.title),
        backgroundColor: _myHandler.color,
        bottom: new TabBar(
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              new Tab(text: _tabs[0].title,),
              new Tab(text: _tabs[1].title,)
            ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}

class MyTabs {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  MyTabs({this.title,this.color});
}
```

Comment: That does solve for the Tabs, but then when I am on a tab and navigate to another page outside the tabs, thats where I am stuck, not sure how to get the appbar title to change.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean, can you elaborate more ?

Comment: So for instance, I call my third tab which is chat, I then get a list of chat threads, when you click on one you go to a new page, which is not a Tab to see the chat detail and reply, etc...  When I go to that new page, I can not change the appbar title, I have to put a new appbar, which is below the main one.  I am trying to be able to change the main appbar title on those new pages.

Comment: How did you end up having a global AppBar ?

Comment: Can you show me some code? because I do not understand how are you using the same AppBar on each page.

Comment: I am not sure what code to show you.  There is alot of code.  Do you want to see main.dart where the main app is instantiated or the page with tabview?

Comment: I just want to understand how the same AppBar is being used for ALL pages?

Comment: I can only surmise that its from the appbar in the scaffold on the main app.  The only time I can change it is if I use the tabview example like the one you have above, when I go to new pages, the appbar is there with my actions, but I can not change the title.

Comment: That is my question, how are you using the same AppBar for all the pages? how are you doing this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157322/discussion-between-aziza-and-robert).

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your architecture. You're not supposed to have a global appBar. One route, one scaffold. Which implies that you'll have a unique appbar for all of your routes. 

We'd need a *real* example to help your further

Comment: > `You're not supposed to have a global appBar. ` -> Is this a Flutter thing?

Answer (score 1):

With the little help of above answer, I could write a simple and beginner friendly code.

- The concept is easy, get current tab index and change title with set state. You need to "detect" when the active tab is changed. That is why we add listener (the one who detects CHANGE, AND ACTS)
- Let me know in comments if below code doesn't make sense

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tcontroller;
  final List<String> titleList = ["Home Page", "List Page", "Message Page"];
  String currentTitle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentTitle = titleList[0];
    _tcontroller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _tcontroller.addListener(changeTitle); // Registering listener
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called, every time active tab is changed
  void changeTitle() {
    setState(() {
      // get index of active tab & change current appbar title
      currentTitle = titleList[_tcontroller.index];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(currentTitle),
        centerTitle: true,
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tcontroller,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.home),
            Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
            Icon(Icons.message),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tcontroller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Text(titleList[0])),
          Center(child: Text(titleList[1])),
          Center(child: Text(titleList[2])),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```